# Non-convexity of an energy functional

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, image-processing

How would I go about showing that the following Mumford Shah functional is not convex?

$$E_{MS}(u,C)=  \int_{\Omega} |u_{0}(x,y) -u(x,y)|^{2}\ dx\ dy + \mu \int_{\Omega \backslash C}|\nabla u(x,y)|^{2}\ dx\ dy + \nu \operatorname{Length}(C) $$

where $\mu,\nu >0$ are constants, $C$ is a smooth closed curve, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is some image domain, and $u_{0}$ is an image, and $u$ is a piecewise smooth approximation to the image.

Not really sure where to begin here, any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: For a **fixed** $C$, as a function of $u$, this functional is convex. It's quadratic. If $C$ varies, depending on $u$, that's a different story. You should clarify this point.

Comment: The method tries to find the minimal curve $C$ that segments a given image $u_{0}(x,y)$ so yes C can vary